# microsoft excel runtime error 1004 - compatabilty issues

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

So I created some code to create and run through a forumla in excel. It works fine for me using Office 365 but not for my colleague who I think is using Excel 2013/16. The error gets thrown somewhere in the code below...microsoft excel runtime error 1004

Please excuse my shoddy code. Is there an obvious reason this works fine for me and not my colleague?

```
Sub BAU()

Application.StatusBar = "Processing BAU"

Sheets("BAU").Activate

Sheets("BAU").Range("$A$3:$BB$128523").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
"BAU"

Sheets("BAU").ShowAllData

Range("BAUFulldata2").ClearContents

Dim endyear As Integer
Dim Baseyear As Integer

endyear = Range("endyear")
Baseyear = Range("Baseyear")
```

' THE LINE BELOW IS WHERE THINGS BREAK

```
Range("i4").Formula2R1C1 = _
    
"=IFERROR(IF(AND(RC3=""Total"",RC4=""Total"",RC5=""Total"",RC6=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C47,),OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C47,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C47,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C47,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C47,),""<>Total""),IF(AND(RC3=""Total"",RC4=""Total"",RC5=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C42,),OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C42,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C4" & _
    ",,,-R3C42,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C42,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C42,),RC6),IF(AND(RC3=""Total"",RC4=""Total"",RC6=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C48,),OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C48,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C48,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C48,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C48,),RC5),IF(AND(RC6=""Total"",RC4=""Total"",RC5=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C" & _
    ",,,-R3C49,),OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C49,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C49,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C49,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C49,),RC3),IF(AND(RC3=""Total"",RC6=""Total"",RC5=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C50,),OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C50,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C50,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C50,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C50,),RC4),IF" & _
    "(AND(RC6=""Total"",RC4=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C51,),OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C51,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C51,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C51,),RC3,OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C51,),RC5),IF(AND(RC5=""Total"",RC6=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C52,),OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C52,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C52,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C52,),RC3,OFFSET(" & _
    "R[-1]C4,,,-R3C52,),RC4),IF(AND(RC3=""Total"",RC6=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C53,),OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C53,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C53,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C53,),RC4,OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C53,),RC5),IF(AND(RC3=""Total"",RC4=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C41,),OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C41,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C41,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1" & _
    "]C5,,,-R3C41,),RC5,OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C41,),RC6),IF(AND(RC4=""Total"",RC5=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C43,),OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C43,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C43,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C43,),RC3,OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C43,),RC6),IF(AND(RC3=""Total"",RC5=""Total""),SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C46,),OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C46,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C" & _
    "46,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C46,),RC4,OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C46,),RC6),IF(RC4=""Total"",SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C40,),OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C40,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C40,),RC3,OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C40,),RC5,OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C40,),RC6),IF(RC3=""Total"",SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C44,),OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C44,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C44,),RC4,OFFSE" & _
    "T(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C44,),RC5,OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C44,),RC6),IF(RC5=""Total"",SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C45,),OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C45,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C45,),RC3,OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C45,),RC4,OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C45,),RC6),IF(RC6=""Total"",SUMIFS(OFFSET(R[-1]C,,,-R3C54,),OFFSET(R[-1]C6,,,-R3C54,),""<>Total"",OFFSET(R[-1]C3,,,-R3C54,),RC3,OFFSET(R[-1]C4,,,-R3C54,)" & _
    ",RC4,OFFSET(R[-1]C5,,,-R3C54,),RC5),IF(RC7=""Carbon (tCO2e)"",SUMIFS(OFFSET(Carbon1718,,R2C,,),Activity,RC3,Category,RC4,Owner,RC5,Sector,RC6),IF(RC7=""Cost (£)"",SUMIFS(OFFSET(Cost1718,,R2C,,),Activity,RC3,Category,RC4,Owner,RC5,Sector,RC6),IF(R3C=Baseyear,0,SUMIFS(OFFSET(CapitalCost,,,,),ActivityProject,RC3,INDIRECT(RC39),""Y"",CategoryProject,RC4,OwnerProject," & _
    "RC5,SectorProject,RC6,CapitalSpendYear,R3C))))))))))))))))))),"""")" & _
    ""
```

Comment: "Somewhere" is not really helpful. Anyhow, I am pretty sure that your formula will have an error and therefore cannot be written into the `Formula2R1C1`-property of the cell. But honestly, this formula looks so complicated that I doubt that anyone will understand it and be able to help you with it.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be an easy solution regarding compatability. As I said, the code works fine for me, no issues at all. Maybe I should have been clearer that more I am looking for some guidance regarding the differences in Excel versions and how that can impact VBA script.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it is perhaps the R1C1-style notation that is causing the issue on my collegues older excel version?

Comment: Unless the collegue uses Excel 2003 or older, no. R1C1-style should work even on 2003, but it couldn't handle 128523 rows.